# Static libraries and constants

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have followed the tutorial at http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/

To make myself a static library. It builds fine. But the issue is I have some constant strings defined in an h file which i have made public in the device and simulator targets in Build Phases>Copy Headers. i.e I have exposed 2 header files to the user. and these constants are to be changed in different projects

Suppose i build the static library with

```
#define PUB_ID @"43"
```

and copy the .a file and the public .h files to a new project and change the value of the constant to

```
#define PUB_ID @"50"
```

The value of PUB_ID remains 43 within the .a file if do an NSLog in it.

I have no idea whats going on here. How do I get this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The #define is a preprocessor macro. What it means is when you built your static library, all the instances of PUB_ID were replaced with @"43".